# Symfony 3 Pagination Form Data

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, symfony

i have a problem.
I use Symfony 3 for my project. In my project i have a litte pagination.

See: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination-pager

On these two buttons i use the href attribute to navigate between sites.
This works perfect. But now comes the problem.
On every page are a few input fields of which i need the values.

But the pager "buttons" are links, so if i click on one "button" the form will not be submitted.
If i change the links to real buttons, the form will be submitted, but i can't change the page, because there is ne href attribute.
I know i have to set the location in the action attribute of the from, but then i can't navigate backwards or forwards.

So what can i do to get the form params and navigate forwards and backwards?

I hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go backwards and forwards, you don't want a submit button for each page. You only want a submit button at the end, which will submit your whole form (all the pages).

What you should do is:

1. Put your pagination and your pages inside a big `<form>` tag, with an `action` attribute if needed.
2. Inside your pages, put your form fields.
3. For the last page of your form, you "Next" link must be replaced by a submit button.

That way, when you submit your form in the last page, all the fields of your different pages will be submitted at once. And you still can navigate backwards and forwards inside your form before submitting.

Comment: Sure? I think that the other form fields get lost when i change/refresh the whole site. So i will only get the form fields from the last page, or?

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood how your pager works, thought it was a Javascript pager. In my opinion, if you want to make a navigable form with pages, I think the best way would actually be to make your pager work with JS (and then follow my answer). But you can also keep your multi-page static form, make each page a "sub-form" and store the entity manipulated by the form in session when each sub-form is submitted. But I already had to do this kind of things, and I really don't like this approach. Up to you!

Comment: Sorry, i didn't know that bootstrap offers functionality for that pager, my bad. Now it works great with bootstraps javascript. Thanks a lot